# 7-segment display in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

So I'm currently writing VHDL code for a 7-segment display that will display (0-F) once each second. I have almost everything done, the only thing I'm stuck on is the controller.

I need to have 4 buttons, the first starts the counter, the second stops it, the third increments it by one, and the last one resets it back to 0 (I already have the last one done, I just need the first three)

Here is my overall code (Note that Problem 2 component is my counter):

```
entity SSD is
port (
   seg : out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
   an3 : out std_logic;
   btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4 : in std_logic;
   clk : in std_logic);
    end SSD;

    architecture Behavioral of SSD is

    component hex7seg is
    port (
        x : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        a_to_g : out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0));
    end component;

    component Problem2 is
    port (
        clr : in std_logic;
        ce : in std_logic;
        clk : in std_logic;
        b : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        tc : out std_logic);
    end component;

component clkdiv is
port (
    rst : in std_logic;
    clk : in std_logic;
    clkout : out std_logic);
end component;

component controller is
port (
    start : in std_logic;
    stop : in std_logic;
    inc : in std_logic;
    rst : in std_logic;
    clk : in std_logic;
    run : out std_logic);
end component;

signal b : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal run : std_logic;
signal clk_1sec : std_logic;
signal tc : std_logic;

begin

U1: hex7seg port map (x => b, a_to_g => seg);

U2: Problem2 port map (clr=>btn4, ce=>run, clk=>clk_1sec, b=>b, tc=>tc);

U3: controller port map (start => btn1, stop => btn2, inc => btn3, rst => btn4, clk => clk_1sec, run => run);

U4: clkdiv port map (rst => btn4, clk => clk, clkout => clk_1sec);

an3 <= '0';

end Behavioral;
```

Here is what I have so far for the controller code:

```
entity controller is
    Port ( start : in  STD_LOGIC;
           stop : in  STD_LOGIC;
           inc : in  STD_LOGIC;
           rst : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           run : out  STD_LOGIC);
end controller;

architecture Behavioral of controller is

begin
    run <= '1';

end Behavioral;
```

I'm not really sure where to go from there to get the other 3 buttons working, any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [It is considered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85757/hdl-questions-stackoverflow-or-electronics-se) that HDL questions are better suited for [Electronics.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com).  VHDL may look like code, but you're really designing hardware layout, not instructions that are executed.

Comment: Thank you Jonathon, I will try that out

Comment: Also, you named your `SSD` architecture `Behavioral`, but all I see are component instantiations and `port map`s. I would call this a "structural" design.

Comment: Would that change the code at all? Or is it just good practice to do so?

Comment: No, you can name the architecture whatever you'd like. It was just a bit misleading.

Comment: -1 Duplicate question in http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/69030/7-segment-display-in-vhdl. Please remove this one.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a process to control your "RUN" signal. this signal must be buffered as you don't want to press "START" all the time. for the "INC" you need to generate something that enables the counter only for one clock cycle. the whole thing could look as indicated below:

```
ctrl: process(clk, rst)
begin
    if rst='1' then
        s_run<='0';
        s_inc<='0';
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        -- button controlled RUN signal for counter

        -- stop counter on "stop"
        if stop='1' then
            s_run<='0';

        -- start counter on "start"
        elsif start='1' then
            s_run<='1';     

        -- enable counter for 1 clock on "inc"
        elsif inc='1' and s_inc='0' then
            s_run<='1';

        -- stop counter 1 clock after "inc"!
        elsif s_inc='1' then
            s_run<='0';

        -- otherwise
        else
            s_run<=s_run;
        end if;

        -- buffer of "inc" for edge detection
        s_inc<=inc;
    end if;
end process ctrl;

-- write output
run <= s_run;
```

NOTE that you have to press your buttons for at least one clock cycle... as your clock is named clk_1sec this might be 1 second.